# Working with a table where both rows and columns can be edited, added or deleted(VB.net)

Tags: sql, vb.net

VB.net
I'm designing a table for my app that displays predefined capabilities for my products.
For example, for a toy product, its anti-scratch and waterproof properties can be marked separately in the form of true or false.
It is clear that I individually delete, edit or add product information in a separate form, and also delete, edit or add specific specification information in a separate form.
My problem is that I want to have a table and display the names of the products in the rows and the specifications that I had previously saved in the columns.
How can I link these columns and rows together?
My goal right now is not what code to have. My question is how to program in general.
Initially, I decided that when I add or remove an attribute, I would also add a column with the same ID in the Products SQL table and fill it with true or false.
Do you have a better and easier suggestion?

When I add a product to the program, I want to check the specifications of that product from the list of specific specifications.
Then show these dependencies in a matrix table.
In this way, it is determined which characteristics are most used in which products.

Update:
An idea came to my mind
What do you think that when I add a row to the second table, I should separately add a column with the ID of that row in the first table.
And every time I delete that row in the second table, I also delete that column with that ID in the first table.
Do you think this is correct and feasible?

Comment: I would use a gridview able to display master-detail relationships as shown in this [image](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/images/win-grid-master-detail-visualization-result.png). But I don't think the standard WinForms controls can do this.

Comment: thank you, i will use gridview and report it back

Comment: Just to make sure I got the project right this far.
Should I store the products in a separate table and store the specifications in a separate table?

Comment: If the specification properties are different for different product types, then yes.

Comment: I still could not solve the problem
I don't know how to store the information related to the relationship between these two tables. Where should I save and how to cover the editing of these two lists in that third table

Comment: An idea came to my mind
What do you think that when I add a row to the second table, I should separately add a column with the ID of that row in the first table.
And every time I delete that row in the second table, I also delete that column with that ID in the first table.
Do you think this is correct and feasible?

Comment: You have 1 to n relationship between Product and Specification. I.e., you have a foreign key in Specification pointing to the primary key in Product. When you delete a specification, this will not delete any product. But you may a have a delete propagation defined in the foreign key constraint, such that when you delete a product, this will delete the related specifications. See: [1 to n relationships tutorial](https://www.google.com/search?q=1+to+n+relationships+tutorial).

Comment: thanks  Olivier ,I think my problem will be solved with the Many to Many relationship. Thank you for your useful tip
Today I will do this in my program to see if I get an answer or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a Many:Many table design:

**Product Table**

- ProductID
- ProductName

**Feature Table**

- FeatureID
- FeatureName

**ProductFeature Table**

- ProductFeatureID
- ProductID
- FeatureID

**Product:ProductFeature** is 1:Many

**Feature:ProductFeature** is also 1:Many

That way **Product:Feature** is Many:Many